# Can I use member function of underlying container of priority_queue

Tags: c++, vector, stl, priority-queue, member-functions

As title, I created a priority_queue(default use vector as underlying container) p. Can I use vector's member function like`p.push_back(a)`or `p.reserve(25)`
or even use `for(auto i:p) {cout << i}`
When I run code below , the compiler(GCC) tell me

> class "std::priority_queue>,
>   >" has no member "reserve"
>   class std::priority_queue, std::greater >'
>   has no member named 'begin'
>   etc.

How should I do to if i want to use the function mentioned above, or they are just forbidden?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    priority_queue<int , vector<int>, greater<int>> p;
    p.push_back(1);
    p.reserve(25);
    for(auto i : p){
        cout << i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would push_back mean for a priority queue?

Comment: I think it will behave like .push eventually.
Just like push_back into vector and reorder to maintain the property.

Comment: But it is called `push_back`, so it would be confusing if the element doesn't end up in the back, and it would make no sense to be able to push something into the back of a priority queue ignoring the priority criteria.

Comment: `priority_queue` has the underlying container in a protected member named `c`. Since it's protected, you need to derive your own class from `priority_queue` before you can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container adapters are designed specifically to abstract away the underlying container. It provides a new abstraction on its own.

So, no, you cannot call members of the vector inside the queue. What you can do however, is call functions on the vector *before* it enters the queue. And then move it in place:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   vector<int>   v;
   v.reserve(25);
   v.push_back(1);

    priority_queue<int , vector<int>, greater<int>> p(greater<int>(), std::move(v));

    return 0;
}
```

Still no way to output the contents of a queue or stack, as you can only access the `top()` element (on purpose, as part of the abstraction).